# Can I get Nginx to log certain types of requests differently?

Tags: configuration, logging, nginx

I want Nginx to log requests that start with */path* to a certain log file. like this:

- *http://domain.com/path/to/dir* = **Logged**
- *http://www.domain.com/to/some/dir/path/* = **Not Logged**
- *http://sub.domain.com/* = **Not Logged**

Sorry if this is vague, but I'm new to the nginx config biz. Feel free to ask questions about what I'm doing, I'll answer them the best I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
location /foobar {
 access_log /var/log/foobar.log;
}
```

Comment: well, crap. That's easy. :D

Thanks, Jorge!